# Simulating range sensors in Stage and publishing to ROS

Tags: ros, simulation, stage, stage-ros, range

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the Stage Manual (http://rtv.github.io/Stage/group__model__ranger.html), the generic `ranger` model that was introduced in Stage 4 should be able to simulate both laser rangefinders and (sonar or IR) range sensors. However, it doesn't look like [stage_ros](https://github.com/ros-simulation/stage_ros) can handle range sensors. I'm inferring that based on the topics published by the `stage_ros` node and the fact that it doesn't include `sensor_msgs/Range`.

Is it just a missing feature that I could implement or am I misunderstanding the `ranger` model?

References:

- http://rtv.github.io/Stage/index.html
- http://wiki.ros.org/stage_ros#Published_topics
- http://answers.ros.org/question/33973/stage-error-in-fuerte/
- http://answers.ros.org/question/58948/stage-tutorial-error-laser-model-type-not-found/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242822/simulating-range-sensors-in-stage-and-publishing-to-ros/) by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1788 on 2016-08-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Usually, the sonar message is `sensor_msgs/PointCloud` or `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2`, and laser message is `sensor_msgs/LaserScan` or `sensor_msgs/PointCloud`.

`sensor_msgs/Range` just contains a single range, so I think it is not used widely.

---

EDIT

I used the pioneer robot simulator `Mobilesim`, which is derived from `stage`. And there is a ros node `rosaria` which get info from `Mobilesim` and publish `sensor_msgs/PointCloud` and `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` for 16 sonar sensors on the pioneer robot.

Maybe you can refer to this.

---

Originally posted by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) with karma: 763 on 2016-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-09-04**:
According to the ROS API documentation, a sonar or IR sensor measurement falls under the `Range` message use cases: http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Range.html Other simulators, such as STDR, do publish `Range` messages: http://wiki.ros.org/stdr_robot?distro=kinetic#Published_Topics

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-09-04**:
I don't see how `PointCloud` is a good fit for sonar/IR. If it's a single sensor, then the `points` list will always be a singleton (thus why not use `Range`).

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-09-04**:
If there are multiple sonar/IR sensors, they are probably placed in different parts of the robot (e.g. around the base) Therefore, they can't be associated with a single `header.frame_id` unless they are transformed to a common frame before publication.

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-09-04**:
Regardless, `stage_ros` doesn't published `PointCloud` messages either. Only `LaserScan` http://wiki.ros.org/stage_ros#Published_topics

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-09-04**:
@Shay I saw your edit. Interesting, I'll take a look. Thanks :-)